# Using JavaScript console in Google Chrome how can I get the index of the selected/active/current Tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to retrieve the index of the currently active/selected/current tab. What is the command to run which will retrieve the Index?

Comment: Are you using a framework or library?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use [Chrome API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/getstarted.html) for this, which is available to extensions and apps.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
    console.log("index:", tab.index);
});
```

Comment: Specifically: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getSelected.

Comment: How can i do it without creating extension? I like to do it right in the console that shows up on the page.

Comment: I cannot access tabs on the console. I can access chrome object right on the console does not have tabs as child elements.

Comment: @RJP Well, you can't. It is available only to extensions.