# Is it possible to go to the right tab via javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there any code to go to the right/left tab on the browser? 
Let's say it's Google Chrome, can I head to the right tab using a javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any code to go to the right/left tab on the browser? Let's
>   say it's Google Chrome, can I head to the right tab using a javascript
>   ?

Nope, that's not possible with Javascript, you can't manipulate browser interface. Though I *think* it is possible if you are going to create a browser addon/plugin.

Comment: Yes it is possible for Chrome Addons if they have the permission set, see [Using JavaScript console in Google Chrome how can I get the index of the selected/active/current Tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7260991/367456)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a shortcut-key for same operation you are asking:

`ctrl+PageUp` , if you can execute anyhow using JavaScript, then you can achieve your target.